# Cannot debug "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of null" error in angular app

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I have recently started learning angular and created this reactive form that takes some inputs from the user. But the hobbies section isnt working correctly and i am getting this error which i cannot debug:

```
AppComponent.html:39 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of null
    at FormArray._forEachChild (forms.js:5718)
    at FormArray._setUpControls (forms.js:5759)
    at new FormArray (forms.js:5385)
    at AppComponent.onAddHobby (app.component.ts:30)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (AppComponent.html:42)
    at handleEvent (core.js:43992)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:45631)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:45246)
    at dispatchEvent (core.js:29803)
    at core.js:42924
```

here is the html and .ts file:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-offset-2">
      <form [formGroup]="signupForm" (ngSubmit) = "onSubmit()">
        <div formGroupName="userData">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              id="username"
              formControlName="username"
              class="form-control">
              <span 
              *ngIf="!signupForm.get('userData.username').valid && signupForm.get('userData.username').touched"
              class="help-block">Invalid Username!</span>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">email</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              id="email"
              formControlName="email"
              class="form-control">
              <span 
              *ngIf="!signupForm.get('userData.email').valid && signupForm.get('userData.email').touched"
              class="help-block">Invalid Email!</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="radio" *ngFor="let gender of genders">
          <label>
            <input
              type="radio"
              formControlName="gender"
              [value]="gender">{{ gender }}
          </label>
        </div>
        <div formArrayName="hobbies">
          <h4>Your hobbies:</h4>
          <button 
          class="btn btn-default" 
          type="button"
          (click)="onAddHobby()">Add Hobby</button>
          <hr>
          <div 
          class="form-group"
          *ngFor="let hobbyControl of getControls(); let i = index">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" [formControlName]="i">
          </div>
        </div>
        <span 
            *ngIf="!signupForm.valid && signupForm.touched"
            class="help-block">Invalid Data!</span>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I think the problem here is with my addHobby() function and the chrome debugger throws an error on the button tag which has this function as the error occurs when i click it.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  genders = ['Male', 'Female'];
  signupForm: FormGroup;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.signupForm = new FormGroup({
      'userData': new FormGroup({
        'username': new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
        'email': new FormControl(
          null, [Validators.required, Validators.email])
      }),
      'gender': new FormControl('Male'),
      'hobbies': new FormArray([])
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.signupForm);
  }

  onAddHobby() {
    const control = new FormArray(null, Validators.required);
    (<FormArray>this.signupForm.get('hobbies')).push(control);
  }

  getControls() {
    return (<FormArray>this.signupForm.get('hobbies')).controls;
  }
}
```

please help me here.

Comment: Did you add FormModule into imports of app.module.ts ?

Comment: yes i did but the problem is still there

Comment: Did you add CommonModule?

Comment: i did now but nothing changed

Answer (score 3):

The culprit is this line:

```js
const control = new FormArray(null, Validators.required);
```

You're passing `null` to the constructor of `FormArray`, which expects an array. See this link for details: https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray.

Since the value is `null`, the function `forEach` could not be called on it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I tried adding child FormControl objects in the FormArray but the problem is that now i cant take an input from the user. Which means that when i press the submit button the hobbies passed in the constructor would be submitted as opposed to the value entered by the user.

Comment: @HassanIftikhar -- if you can create a working demo, it would be much helpful in debugging.

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned in other answer, the error comes from declaring `control` as a null FormArray. Anyway, I don't see how it even should be a `FormArray`, assumingly according to your template, it should be a `FormControl` instead:

```ts
onAddHobby() {
  const control = new FormControl(null, Validators.required);
  (<FormArray>this.signupForm.get('hobbies')).push(control);
}
```

**[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kt8r7w?file=src/app/app.component.html)**

PS: I think it's cleaner to use `FormBuilder` instead of using `new FormArray([]) / new FormGroup({...})`

Comment: well the thing is that i was following this tutorial on udemy and was recreating the app made by the instructor. the use of FormArray was so that i could get to learn how it works. probably the code worked as it is in an older version of angular.

Comment: No, that code would not have even worked in previous versions ;) Your template as written, demands a `FormControl` to be added to the formarray, not nesting a formarray inside the formarray. So if you were following a course, there must be either an error in your template or ts code, since the codes do not match, unless you push a form control to the formarray, no matter the version of angular.